# How to discard some old commits in the same branch?

Tags: git, commit

Few weeks ago, I made some changes all in Master branch. Now I want to discard them all.

Please take a look at this:

[image]

those 4 highligted commits should be discarded/undo (as if there were no such changes). Is it possible to do so in git?

Comment: It's possible but you will need to rewrite the history of the master branch, which I believe is a shared branch. Another way of doing it will be simply to revert them. All depends on how you manage the git workflow in your project.

Answer (score 0):

See this github blog.

[See this link](https://github.blog/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/)

Use `git revert`